# Reload TableView data only after downloading everything from the firebase database Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have been searching for a while now, but I don't know how to deal with this problem.
I have a Firebase Database with some data and the links to images stored into the Storage.
I want my UICollectionView to be reloaded after I downloaded every single image from the database, and not only the first one.

```
newRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshotOne) in
        for child in snapshotOne.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key

            newRef.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshotTwo) in
                for child in snapshotTwo.children {
                    let snappotto = child as! DataSnapshot
                    var imageDownloaded: UIImage?

                    if let dictionary = snappotto.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        let url = URL(string: dictionary["imageURL"] as! String)
                        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print("[Error]: \(String(describing: error))")
                                return
                            }

                            imageDownloaded = UIImage(data: data!)

                            let person = Person(name: dictionary["name"] as! String, surname: dictionary["surname"] as! String, tags: [.castana], image: imageDownloaded!)
                            self.storedData.append(person)

                            self.filteredData = self.storedData

                            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                            }

                        }.resume()
                    }
                }
            }) { (error) in
                print("[Error]: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print("[Error]: \(error)")
    }
```

This is the code I use, but this updates my UICollectionView after only the first image is downloaded, and with that it endsIgnoringInteractionEvents - and allows the user to reload the data again and again and this causes a lot of images to duplicate.

How can I move the reloading and the endIgnoringInteractionEvents after every single item from my database is downloaded?

The database is structured like this:

```
| folder
-| user
--| autoId
---| name
---| surname
---| imageUrl
--|autoId
---| name
---| surname
---| imageUrl
-| user
--| autoId
---| name
---| surname
---| imageUrl
```

Thanks a lot, NicopDev

Comment: Your question says you are using Storage - does that mean Firebase Storage? If so, why are you using this `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!)`? Using [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files) would simplify the code. Also, you could created a Dispatch group and add each download to that group. When they are all done the group.notify would fire indicating all tasks are complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nesting observers on nested data, which seems like a waste of code. When you attach an observer to a location, all data under that location is loaded already.

So you can just loop over the nested snapshot to get the same result:

```
newRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let userSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
        let userKey = userSnapshot.key

        for child in userSnapshot.children {
            let imageSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
            var imageDownloaded: UIImage?
            ...
```

---

With that out of the way, let's move on to your real question: how can you detect when all images have loaded.

One simple, cross-platform way to do this is by simply counting how many images you have loaded, and compare that to how many images you know exist. Since you have a tree of only existing images, you can do both in a iteration over the double nested structure

```
let knownImageCount = 0 // we start with no knowledge of any image
let loadedImageCount = 0 // we also haven't loaded any image yet

for child in snapshot.children {
    let userSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
    let userKey = userSnapshot.key

    knownImageCount = knownImageCount + userSnapshot.childrenCount // we've found out about N more images

    for child in userSnapshot.children {
        let imageSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
        var imageDownloaded: UIImage?
        ...

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            ...

            loadedImageCount = loadedImageCount + 1 // we loaded an additional image

            if loadedImageCount == knownImageCount {
                ... // we've loaded all known images, we're done!
            }
        }.resume()
```

Comment: I'm now getting [link](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ascapp-20bf1.appspot.com/o/EECB64BF-5D2C-4069-AC65-A3C2CC71C043.png?alt=media&token=1d9c4b48-68a6-4c65-8f01-121012dafd9b) this type of error. What did I do?

Comment: That means you've exceeded the (likely free) quota for your project. I recommend searching for error messages, as this looks quite relevant: https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+storage+Quota+has+been+exceeded+for+this+project

Comment: @Vipera74 Can't that error also be result of trying to access a non-existent url? So if url were nil for example here `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!` <- force unwrapping optional. Adding in some basic error checking may provide a bit more details as to which one if that's the case. So you could test for nil URL and if so, present an error. Likewise, if error is not nil when trying to read the URL, present the error and whatever the url was. Just a thought.

Comment: Hey Jay. The error message you now get is indeed that the object doesn't exist. When I tried it yesterday, the quota was exceed and I got the error message in the link I gave. This is one of those reasons why it's best to not use linked content on Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: You were right, I exceeded the quota because I was using PNG images instead of JPEG compression, and the link I sent is probably the way firebase populates images links when you exceed